# Why does my MediaPlayer stop working if I "interrupt" it?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want my button to be "spammable". This means that if I tap on the button repeatedly the MediaPlayer starts all over again.

```
firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (firstTextView.getText().equals("Hello world!")) {

                firstTextView.setText("You clicked!");


            } else {

                firstTextView.setText("Hello world!");

            }

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                mediaPlayer.stop();

            }

            mediaPlayer.start();

        }
    });
```

When I interrupt the MediaPlayer when it is playing, it stops and never starts again. Why?

**EDIT**: The problem is that I called stop(). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), you need to re-prepare the `MediaPlayer` (emphasis mine):

> Once in the Stopped state, **playback cannot be started until
>   [`prepare()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare()) or [`prepareAsync()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync()) are called** to set the MediaPlayer object
>   to the Prepared state again.

Comment: So I "prepare" it after I call ".stop()"?

Comment: @MishilD. Yes, `mediaPlayer.prepare()` after calling `stop()` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are stopping the player because you are calling `mediaPlayer.stop()` this makes the `MediaPlayer` state to go in `Stopped` state. It will continue to play again when you call `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()` and has its preparation callback fired to start the playing media.